# MatPlotLib connected wrong datapoint

Tags: matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have this simple boto3 code to get CPU ultilization for instances. The data i get was correct but somehow the way Matplotlib displaying my data is wrong.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
        plt.scatter(timestamps, cpu_values)
        plt.plot(timestamps, cpu_values, marker='o', markersize=3) 
        plt.xlabel('Time')
        plt.ylabel('CPU Utilization (%)')
        plt.title('CPU Utilization for EC2 Instance: ' + instance_id)
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.xticks(rotation=45)
        # plt.tight_layout()
        plt.savefig('cpu_utilization_plot.png')  # Save the plot as an image
        plt.show()
```

This is how i plot and the output is this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7xBh.png)

Instead of like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/109Rr.png)
(ref picture: GeeksForGeeks)

Where am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your timestamps most be sorted prior to plotting